# What does the standard say about static_cast between fundamental type?

Tags: c++, casting

I am curious to learn what the standard say about cast between types, (not classes).

For example,

```
unsigned long long int ulli = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long int>::max();
char c = static_cast<char>(ulli);
```

On my compiler, (VS2015), this does not even throw a warning, (c = -1 in that case).

But the `size of char` and the `size of unsigned long long int` are not the same. Is it a problem? Is that behaviour undefined?

Does the standard say what should happen in the case where you are trying to cast a variable into a smaller one?

Is it even safe?

What about the opposite case, trying to cast a small value into a larger one?

```
char c = std::numeric_limits<char>::max();
unsigned long long int ulli = static_cast<unsigned long long int>(c);
```

Does the standard guarantee that it will work, or is it all up to the compiler to protect the developer?

Comment: Note that `char` is special because it isn't specified whether it is signed or unsigned. And the answer would depend on that.

Comment: Ooops, thanks @WhozCraig, I fixed it to a `unsigned long long int` cast.

Comment: I think the general rule is that it's well defined if the value of the original variable is within the range of the target type.

Comment: *does not even throw a warning* why would it? You're explicitly casting, telling the compiler 'hey I know what I'm doing'. If you'd omit the static_cast you'd get warnings.

Comment: What do you mean by "it will work"?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, what I meant was, is such a cast guaranteed to be successful by the standard or is it implementation specific, the, somewhat related question you closed this to kind of answers my question(s).

Comment: @stijn,  this is my question really, is the fact that VS2015 not raising a warning/error expected or is the implementation of the static_cast in this case not valid as per the standard.